# my Java program does not draw rectangles on the entire window

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw a rectangle 80*80 on a 800*800 window but for some reason I'm able to draw two columns only!! I feel like there's something about Java that I'm missing. I've a class called: DrawBoard which has method that overrides paint() method. An object of this class is created in another class called: DrawWindow. Then, in Main, I create a new DrawWindow object.
Here's my code:

`

```
package legalGameMove;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawBoard extends JPanel{

int r = 0, c = 0;
int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

public void paint(Graphics g){

    int count = 0;
    while(count <= 10){

        if((count % 2) == 0){

        for(int i = 0; i <= w; i++){                
            for(int j = 0; j <= h; j++){

                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.fillRect(r , c, 80, 80);

                r+= 80;
                    g.setColor(Color.white);
                    g.fillRect(r, c, 80, 80);
                r+= 80;                 
            }
        }

    }else{

        for(int i = 0; i <= w; i++){                
            for(int j = 0; j <= h; j++){

                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.fillRect(r , c, 80, 80);

                r+= 80;
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.fillRect(r, c , 80, 80);
                r+= 80;                 
            }
        }
    }
        r = 0;
        c+= 80; 
        count++;
}


}
}
```

`

```
 package legalGameMove;
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 public class DrawWindow extends JFrame{
public DrawWindow(){        

    super("game board");
    Container cont = getContentPane();
    //setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    DrawBoard db = new DrawBoard();
    cont.add(db, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(800,800);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields `w` and `h` are initialized when `DrawBoard` is constructed, where the width and height still are not layouted (zero). Move those declarations inside the `paint`.

And preferably use `paintComponent` for drawing.

Comment: I kept using paint(), but simply made my foor-loops go to 800 since this is the window size and it is constant, as well as the rectangles height and width. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!